# Fill na values in dataframe after merge

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-merge

I have 2 dataframes I want to merge on first name and contact email returning all of the values from df2.

Sample of data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['Elle', 'Kelly', 'ellemoore@email.com', 2],
['Amanda','Johnson', 'johnson.amanda@email.com', 5], 
['Jay', 'Rogers', 'jay.rogers@email.com', 4], 
['David','Connor', 'famconnor@email.com', 3],
['Rachel','Connor','famconnor@email.com', 2],
['Anne','Smith','anniesmith@email.com', 4],
['Anne','Smith', 'asmith@email.com', 2],
['Dani', 'Carter', 'daniellecarter@email.com', 3],
['Drake', 'Walker', 'dwalker@email.com', 2]], 
columns = ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email', 'Rating'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1040, 'City'], 
['Dani','Carter-Hampton', 'daniellecarter@email.com', 1040, 'New York'],
['Anne','Smith','anniesmith@email.com', 1040, 'New York'], 
['David', 'Connor', 'famconnor@email.com', 1040, 'Chicago'], 
['Jay', 'Rogers','jrogers@email.com', 1040, 'Los Angeles'], 
['Anne','Smith', 'asmith@email.com', 1040, 'Houston'],
['Amanda','Johnson','johnson.amanda@email.com', 1040, 'Los Angeles'],
['Rachel', 'Connor', 'famconnor@email.com', 1040, 'Chicago'],
['Elle', 'Moore-Kelly', 'moorekellyentertainment@email.com', 1040, 'Los Angeles'],
['Drake', 'Walker', 'walkerproductions@email.com', 1040, 'Los Angeles']],
columns = ['First Name','Last Name','Contact Email','Movie Id','Location'])
```

merge

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, left_on = ['First Name', 'Email'], right_on =  ['First Name', 'Contact Email'], how = 'right')
```

Output of merge
[image]

The problem is some of the rows are unable to match because of differences between name and email in both tables, so I want to perform another merge on first name and last name to fill in the missing nan values. I tried using the combine_first function but because the indices are different it results in mismatched rows and duplicates. How do I go about this?

Desired Output after the first merge to fill in na values

[image]

Comment: **merged['Last Name_x'].combine_first(merged['Last Name_y'])** How about this

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Lazyer's comment, I would use pandas method chaining and use `combine_first` to combine the `Last Name_x` and `Last Name_y` columns and also the `Email` and `Contact Email`.

```
merged = (
    df1
    .merge(df2, left_on=['First Name', 'Email'], right_on=['First Name', 'Contact Email'], how ='right')
    .assign(**{
        'Last Name': lambda x: x['Last Name_x'].combine_first(x['Last Name_y']),
        'Email': lambda x: x['Email'].combine_first(x['Contact Email'])
    })
    .drop(['Last Name_x', 'Last Name_y', 'Contact Email'], axis='columns')
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to get it to also include the values in the Rating column that are also missing?

Comment: What would you fill the missing values in the rating column with? Ratings are not included in df2. If you want to fill with a default value you could call `merged['Rating'].fillna('default value')`